# Firebase realtime database warning email not coming anymore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

We have been using firebase **"firebase": "^8.3.1"** and our rules were set as simple as

```
 "rules": {
     ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
     ".write": "auth.uid !== null"

  }
```

and we used to get warning email everyday morning
[image]

and suddenly from last week we are not getting such emails any more.

- What might have stopped sending warning emails?
- How to get warning emails?

PS: Email alert notification is enabled in settings
[image]

Answer (score 2):

*firebaser here*

This might be the first time that someone complains about *not* getting these emails.

That said: if your database is still getting traffic, you should also be getting these emails. If that is not the case, can you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting?

Comment: this emails are definitely very important as to be aware of insecure rules ( when you work with a large team of developers )
Btw, data is still getting traffic but no emails. thnx for your input

Comment: update:
Firebase support could not help. They said to update the rule not matter what.

Comment: They right about that of course, but it's interesting that the emails didn't show up. You might want to check in https://console.firebase.google.com/subscriptions/overview to ensure that receiving email alerts for the project is enabled.

Comment: I did. unchecked and checked again the email notifications too but nothing helped.